# Ways to make $n$-digit numbers out of a list of $n$ digits of $k$ types

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we have a list of digits, which has $n_1$ digits of kind $a$, $n_2$ digits of kind $b$, $n_3$ digits of kind $c$.
How can I get the number of numbers with $n_1 + n_2 + n_3$ digits that can be made out of the digits from the list?

Each digit from the list can be used just once, so each number will have only $n_1$ digits of kind a; however, there is no difference between all the digits of the a kind, all the digits from the $b$ kind and so on. So $ab_1b_2c$ is just the same as $ab_2b_1c$.

(Example:
List: 1, 2, 2, 3;
Possibilities:
1223, 1232, 1323, 1332, 2123, 2132, 2213, 2231, 2313....)

Comment: See multinomial coefficient: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to consider at first the overall number of permutations that is

$$(n_1+n_2+n_3)!$$

and then recognize that for each kind we have $n_i!$ identical permutations therefore finally we obtain

$$\frac{(n_1+n_2+n_3)!}{n_1!n_2!n_3!}$$

Comment: Thanks! You really helped me.

Comment: @בנימיןליפשיץ You are welcome! Bye